# how to dynamically call a method while respecting privacy

Tags: ruby, reflection, visibility

Using dynamic method calls (`#send` or `#method`) the methods' visibility is ignored.
Is there a simple way to dynamically call a method that will fail calling a private method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I know - you need method public_send:

> ```
> ----------------------------------------------------- Object#public_send
>      obj.public_send(symbol [, args...])  => obj
>
>      From Ruby 1.9.1
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>      Invokes the method identified by _symbol_, passing it any arguments
>      specified. Unlike send, public_send calls public methods only.
>
>         1.public_send(:puts, "hello")  # causes NoMethodError
> ```

Comment: this is not available in ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Actually, send is sufficient in 1.9 I believe. Rumor has it send cares in 1.9 but __send__ doesn't. But I haven't confirmed this.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead of `send`:

```
my_object.public_send :method, *args
```

It's new to Ruby 1.9, so for older Ruby, you can [`require 'backports/1.9.1/kernel/public_send'`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ruby-1.9, you can use `Object#public_send` which does what you want.

If you use ruby-1.8.7 or earlier you have to write your own `Object#public_send`

```
class Object
  def public_send(name, *args)
    unless public_methods.include?(name.to_s)
      raise NoMethodError.new("undefined method `#{name}' for \"#{self.inspect}\":#{self.class}")
    end
    send(name, *args)
  end
end
```

Or you could write your own `Object#public_method` which behaves like `Object#method` but only for public methods

```
class Object
  def public_method(name)
    unless public_methods.include?(name.to_s)
      raise NameError.new("undefined method `#{name}' for class `#{self.class}'")
    end
    method(name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I don't understand why you want to do so, you can use `eval`.

```
class Klass
  private
    def private_method(arg)
    end
end

k = Klass.new
m = "private_method"
eval "k.#{m}('an arg')"

NoMethodError: private method `private_method' called for #<Klass:0x128a7c0>
    from (irb):15
    from (irb):15
```

Comment: Eval is realy bad. You need to check beforehand, if m really containts only a method name. `l= "inspect; \`rm -rf *\`; puts"` Then the attaker will try to fool you by thinking of something that looks to you like a method name, but realy is not.

Answer (score 0):

It's true though, eval really is I think the only way to actually do it pre-1.9. If you want to read more about visibility Jamis Buck wrote an [awesome article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby) about what method visibility actually means in Ruby.

Much like other things in Ruby visibility is ever so slightly different than other languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `eval`, `send` or `public_send`, or you want [better performance](http://blog.khd.me/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/), use the `public_method` [method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-public_method):

`obj.public_method('my_method_name').call`

You can add arguments like this:

`obj.public_method('my_method_name').call('some_argument_1', 'some_argument_2')`